# Trying to send HTTP Requests to Ubuntu VM on Google Cloud

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, virtual-machine

I have a node server being run on a google console Ubuntu VM. The server launches to the proper port, but whenever I try to HTTP request it, it times out. I was wondering if there was a setting I need to change on google console, or if anyone know what I am doing wrong?

I start the server on the VM using this code:
PORT=3001 node bin/www

Thanks.

Comment: Did you create a [Firewall Rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#firewall_rules_in_gcp) to allow traffic in said port?

Comment: No I did not. I keep trying to use hurl.it to send basic GET and POST requests and it constantly times out

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned in the comments you need to [create a firewall rule](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-firewalls) to allow incoming traffic to your instance on port 3001.

The easier way you can allow traffic to your instance would be:

1 - Tag your instance with some descriptive name, like `nodejs-server`

```
gcloud compute instances add-tags [YOUR INSTANCE NAME] --tags nodejs-server
```

2 - Create a firewall policy allowing tcp connections from anywhere to your instance on port 3000:

```
gcloud compute firewall-rules create allow-3000 --allow tcp:3000  --source-ranges 0.0.0.0/0 --target-tags nodejs-server
```

3 - Wait until the policy is applied and try again. If your server is listening on port 3000 you should get a response now.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. They were very helpful, and the solution. :)

Comment: If this solved your issue please consider marking the answer as accepted: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers